# OnComplete from AjaxOptions is never triggered and I don´t get any error! Why?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

Using ajax.ActionLinkall works fine except the OnComplete functions is never triggered.

The code is:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(User.Identity.Name,"UserSettings","Account",   new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "Get", UpdateTargetId = "conteudoDinamico", OnComplete=" _loadDialogSettings " })
```

I don´t get any error, only the function _loadDialogSettings is never called.

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a direct copy and paste from your page, I notice that your `OnComplete` callback name has spaces, i.e.

```
" _loadDialogSettings "
```

If those are also in your code, try removing them, i.e.

```
"_loadDialogSettings"
```